# I want to clear my doubts about RAM speed?

Tags: memory, cpu

My processor' frequency is 1.7 GHz and i want to add 4 GB RAM to my system.I want to know that RAM  what speed should i buy so that it is compatible with my processor and why ??

Answer (score 1):

You don't give enough information to answer what exact type of memory you'll need, but go to a major vendor such as [crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/) or [kingston.com](http://www.kingston.com/) and they will let you shop by brand/model and let you find the answer for your system.